# Find closure of the following set

Tags: general-topology

Find the closure of the set in $\mathbb R$: $$S=\left\{\frac{a}{p^n}\in \mathbb{R} \mid a \in \mathbb Z, n \in \mathbb N \right\}$$ w.r.t usual topology on $\mathbb {R}$ for a fixed prime $p \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Sorry, Edited the question now.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I would suggest that you read the [Guidelines for homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), such as: *"Please do not just copy and paste the exact question text from your homework sheet"* and *"Show your work"*.

Comment: Since any number $b$ can be written as $\frac{b.p^n}{p^n}$ for a prime $p$, so I am guessing the set must be dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By choice of letter it seems to be implied that $p$ is prime, though this is actually not necessary to assume. The closure is all of $\mathbb R$. To see this, let $x\in \mathbb R$ and choose $\epsilon>0$. Let $n$ be such that $p^n>1/\epsilon$ and choose $a$ such that $-1\leq a-p^nx\leq 1$. Then $$-\epsilon<a/p^n-x<\epsilon$$ Hence any neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of the set, so we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $a_n = \lfloor {x \over {1 \over p^n}} \rfloor$. Then ${a_n \over p^n} \in S$,
and
${x \over {1 \over p^n}} -1 < a_n \le {x \over {1 \over p^n}}$. Dividing across
by $p_n$ gives
$x-{1 \over p^n} < {a_n \over p^n} \le x$ and so $|x-{a_n \over p^n} | \le {1 \over p^n}$. Since $p>1$, we see that ${a_n \over p^n} \to x$.

Hence $\bar{S} = \mathbb{R}$.